# How to create a table with collected items in Hive?

Tags: hive, ddl

This may be really nothing but as i am new to hive. I don't know how to do this in Hive?
I am trying to create a external table in hive, in which one of the columns has array as data type. My sample data looks like this:

```
QuRYeRnAuXM EvilSquirrelPictures 1135 Pets&Animals 252 1075 4.96 46 86 gFa1YMEJFag nRcovJn9xHg 3TYqkBJ9YRk
```

Now, here is the problem my columns are '\t' separated and I want the last three columns(gFa1YMEJFag nRcovJn9xHg 3TYqkBJ9YRk) placed in one column namely related_video_ids. I tried and came up with DDL for my table, here's how it looks:

```
create external table youtube(video_id char(12), uploader string, time_of_est int, 
category string, len int, views int, ratings float, num_of_rat int, comments int,
related_video_ids array<struct<col1:string,col2:string,col3:string>>) row format delimited
fields terminated by '\t' 
collection items terminated by '\t' 
location '/youtube/';
```

But Every time, I write the above Query in Hive I get results like:

```
QuRYeRnAuXM  EvilSquirrelPictures   1135    Pets & Animals  252     1075    4.96000003815   46  86  [{"col1":"gFa1YMEJFag","col2":null,"col3":null}]
```

Please help me to get correct DDL for my table.

Comment: can you change any of the `fields 
terminated by` and `collection items terminated by` ?

Comment: @devツ No, i cannot change the columns in dataset itself.

Comment: then how will hive know if it's collection field or normal field if delimiter is same?

Comment: @devツ That's what the problem is..Isn't there any other way around?

Comment: After gFa1YMEJFag there is  `\t`. hive will consider afterwards as new fields. So you are losing  **nRcovJn9xHg 3TYqkBJ9YRk** . AFAIK there is no work around for this

Comment: @devツ Thanks for your help.